# How can i use the same custom cell in a single tableview differently depending on different conditions?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview and a custom cell. I have 3 conditions which the user selects in the previous screen (number of adults , children and infants).

How do i present the custom cell in the tableview depending on the number of adults , children and infants.
(lets say user selects 1 adult, 2 children and 3 infant)
Cell count works fine. Total number of cells i get is as expected.

I tried using something like

i declared 3 variables adultcounttb , childcounttb, infantcounttb in the tableviewcontroller.

i have get adultcount , childcount and infantcount from previous screen

```
if(adultcounttb < adultcount )
{
let cell =  (declaring)
cell.titlelabel.text = "adult"
adultcounttb  += 1
return cell
}
else if (childcounttb < childcountt)
{
let cell =  (declaring)
cell.titlelabel.text = "child"
childcounttb += 1
return cell
}
else if .....



}
else
{
return UITableviewcell()
}

This works as intended but whenever i scroll , the cells just disappears and becomes blank ( i know its because the else part is getting called) . How can i fix it so that the cells dont disappear or go blank when tableview gets scrolled?
```

Comment: @RajeshKumar R   Basically 3 variables to make sure that i get required number of cells of each type. (like 1 adult, 2 child , 4 infant). Is there a better way to display X number of adult cells, Y number of child cells and Z number of infant cells ( X Y Z are chosen by user in previous screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be implementing a table view as if you are writing a C-style for loop, with the `XXXcounttb` variables as the counters. You should never do this.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you are given an `indexPath` and you are supposed to return a cell that should be at that index path. Your code doesn't even care about the index path. That's a big indicator that you are doing something wrong.

In fact, you can work out what cell should be returned just by looking at the index path given and the `XXXcount` variables passed from the previous VC. You don't need the `XXXcounttb` variables at all.

Assuming you are showing all the cells in a single section, you can do this:

```
if indexPath.row < adultCount {
    // return an adult cell
} else if indexPath.row < adultCount + childCount {
    // return a child cell
} else {
    // return an infant cell
}
```

If you are showing each type of cell in a different section, it's even easier:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    // return an adult cell
} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    // return a child cell
} else {
    // return an infant cell
}
```

Comment: Wow THANKS A LOT. I spent half a day thinking on how to fix this. This makes sense, also if i may, i have another question. Each cell has 4 fields, and user types into those 4 fields. I want to save whatever user types in those fields . 

(Lets say 1 adultcell, 2 childcell and 3 infant cell. User types details of adult in first cell0, details of children in cell1 and cell2 and details of infants in cell3,cell4,cell5)

How do i save the details of each person separately ? (i am trying to sent the details of each person to server using alamofire)

Comment: @Zyfe3r It seems like you are making a form. [Eureka forms](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) might make your life easier. And if you have a new question, please post a new question, instead of asking it in the comments.

Comment: I will mark your question as answered as soon i test this code :)

Comment: I get ( Ambiguous reference to operator function '<'. ) error on if indexPath.row < adultCount { }

How do i fix it?

Edit : It was because I the original adultcount wasn't int value. Simply changing it to int fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Change your custom cell to have a reference to its type like this. And create a init method with the type

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    enum PassengerType: String {
        case adult
        case child
        case infant
    }
    var currentPassengerType: PassengerType?

    let titlelabel = UILabel()
    let nameTxtField = UITextField()
    let ageTxtField = UITextField()

    init(passengerType: PassengerType) {
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.currentPassengerType = passengerType
    }
}
```

In UITableViewController class create an array of the custom cell class. In viewDidLoad create cells based on the count passed from the previous view controller. And use this array in tableView data source methods.

```
class TableVC: UITableViewController {

    var passengerCells = [TableCell]()
    var adultCount = 0
    var childCount = 0
    var infantCount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        passengerCells += (0..<adultCount).map { _ in TableCell(passengerType: .adult) }
        passengerCells += (0..<childCount).map { _ in TableCell(passengerType: .child) }
        passengerCells += (0..<infantCount).map { _ in TableCell(passengerType: .infant) }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return passengerCells.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = passengerCells[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = passengerCells[indexPath.row].currentPassengerType?.rawValue
        return cell
    }
    @objc func submitBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        passengerCells.forEach { cell in
            print(cell.currentPassengerType?.rawValue)
            print(cell.nameTxtField.text!)
            print(cell.ageTxtField.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

In submitBtnAction method I've printed all passenger details with passenger type info. You can send these details in api